# MVC3 changes not saving when controlled disabled

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, permissions, form-helpers

I'm trying to disable MVC3 controls dynamically based on the user's permission. It works fine and automatically sets to a default value when changes are made. But when saving after clicking the submit button none of the changes are saved. This only happens when the control is disabled.

****UPDATE****

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    @if (!disabled)
                    {

                        @Html.TextBox("EffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate.FormatShortDate(), new { @class = "date" })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.TextBox("ReadOnlyEffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate.FormatShortDate(), new { @class = "date", @disabled = "disabled" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EffectiveDate)
                    }
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
                </div>
```

jqueryscript

```
$("#DistributionId").change(function () {
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            $("#TermDate").val("12/31" + currentYear);
            $("#EffectiveDate").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
            $("#ReadOnlyEffectiveDate").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
            $("#EffectiveDate").change(); 
        });
```

the value for #ReadOnlyEffectiveDate does not update #EffectiveDate does but saving still doesn't work.

Comment: disabled field values dont get posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled fields do not get posted back.  If you needed to see which controls are disabled you could use JQuery to enable them and then post them back and then disable them again in your form.

Comment: It doesn't look like he's disabling them, only making them readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in an `else` block, you could just rename your text box to something other than `"EffectiveDate"`, then the hidden field you have there will be posted and the model binder will know to use that value rather than the disabled text box.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked either. Will post changes above